# Make Jupyter Notebook accessible by multiple users on server

Tags: ipython

I set up a Jupyter server on the server in my lab. I would like to make the notebooks accessible to multiple users via their browser, and allow them to edit the notebook. I followed the [instruction](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html) on Jupyter website. But my colleagues have trouble to connect to the kernel: `Connecting to kernel` is always flashing.

Right now I don't have privilege to install python3.x, so I am interested in solutions other than JupyterHub. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using notebook for multiple users. You can try making them read-only
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051037/304209).

Answer (score 0):

From https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/:

> [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub) is the best way to serve [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for multiple users. Because JupyterHub manages a separate Jupyter environment for each user, it can be used in a class of students, a corporate data science group, or a scientific research group. It is a multi-user **Hub** that spawns, manages, and proxies multiple instances of the single-user [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) server.

Comment: Please make sure to _quote_ things you are quoting. Otherwise this is plagiarism, and that is taken _very_ seriously here.

Comment: Also, please note that [link-only answers are strongly discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627).