# What to do when github does not load my jupyter notebook graphs/plots?

Tags: python, git, github, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to solve my problem for a long time but now, I don't know what to do. The problem is - I'm uploading a jupyter notebook on my Github but it is not loading any of the graphs/plots. All the text uploads but not the graphs. I've tried uploading it again and again but I can't seem to find a solution. I've also tried nbviewer but still no luck. Please please help.
The first message that comes after clicking on the notebook is "Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?" after trying for some time the notebook uploads but without GRAPHS!

Comment: A comprehensive answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501883